# Uso correto de "cujo", "cuja" e seus plurais

Tags: concordância

Qual é a forma correta de usar as palavras "cujo", "cuja" e seus plurais?

Por exemplo, a frase abaixo é correta?

> O filho cuja mãe é *coruja*, acaba sendo mais mimado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## cu·jo

> pronome relativo
>
> 1. Do qual; dos quais; de quem. (É também pronome interrogativo pouco usado.) substantivo masculino
> 2. [Antigo]  Dono; sujeição.
> 3. [Brasil, Informal]  Designação vaga de pessoa cujo nome se desconhece ou se quer omitir. = DITO-CUJO
>
> "cujo", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/cujo [consultado em
> 27-07-2015].

---

Estes pronomes **cujo**, **cuja**, **cujas**, **cujos** concordam sempre com o substantivo que se lhe segue, nesse caso:

> O filho **cuja mãe** é *coruja*, acaba sendo mais mimado.

A concordância é sempre feita com o substantivo que se lhe segue independentemente do sujeito da frase:

> Os filhos **cuja mãe** é *coruja*, acabam sendo mais mimados.

Se usássemos pai em vez de mãe teríamos **cujo**.

No plural:

> O filho **cujos progenitores** são *corujas*, acaba sendo mais mimado.
>
> Os filhos **cujos progenitores** são *corujas*, acabam sendo mais mimados.

Fonte: [Pronome «cujo»](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronome-cujo/3553)

---

Como disse o @bfavaretto e muito bem:

> Cujo (a/os/as) já contém o artigo, e é incorreto repeti-lo. Ou seja,
> não é "cuja a mãe", e sim *cuja mãe*, etc.

Comment: *Cujo* (a/os/as) já contém o artigo, e é incorreto repeti-lo. Ou seja, não é "cuja a mãe", e sim *cuja mãe* etc.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu tinha colocado assim, podes ver as minhas edições, decidi manter a concordância com a pergunta. Mas vou editar.

Comment: Não tinha visto suas edições. A da pergunta eu reverti, porque ele está justamente perguntando se aquela forma está correta (e não está).

Comment: @bfavaretto não está nas edições, deve ter sido nas edições dentro dos 5 minutos. Eu corrigi a pergunta porque acho que a intenção do autor não é essa. Mas pode-se perguntar.

Comment: É uma boa oportunidade pra incluir *na resposta* que não se deve usar "cujo o" ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto o [AP já respondeu](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23058360#23058360) e fiz rollback

Comment: @JorgeB. O Priberam lista *dito-cujo* como brasileirismo, mas em Portugal também se diz. Pelo menos no meu :)